# Xcodeを使っていますが、良いメソッドの分類方法を知りたいです。

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

`//MARK: -` としてナビゲーターのリストに表示されるメソッド名を
プログラム全体の見通しがよくなったり、可読性が増したり、
開発効率が上がるような分類方法を知りたいのですが、
一般的に知られた方法や、優れた方法はあるのでしょうか？

・大分類＞中分類＞小分類

みたいな分類方法はないですか？

・あるいは、そのあたりの指針を示した資料などありますか？

・今のところなんとなく、下のように関係のあるものをまとめているだけです。

```
 //MARK: - フェッチ
 //MARK: - Common
 //MARK: - ScrollView
 //MARK: - CollectionView
 //MARK: - TableView
 //MARK: - 新しいアイテムをつくる
 //MARK: - Item 操作
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

僕の場合は、Objective-Cなので、`//MARK:-` を使わずに、`#pragma mark`でコードの区分けをしていますが、
こんな感じですね。基本はクラスの中でどんな役割を持っているか？を`MARK:-`で、そのなかでのまとまりを`MARK:`で区切って見出しを付けていくと良いと思っています

```
#pragma mark - synthesize properties
#pragma mark - class method
#pragma mark - constructor / destructor
#pragma mark - override
#pragma mark - properties
#pragma mark - actions
#pragma mark - messages
#pragma mark - private
#pragma mark - delegate
#pragma mark - C functions
```

`//MARK:`同様、`-`を付けるか付けないかで区切り線が入るか入らないかが変わります。
上から順に、`@property`の`@synthesize`宣言をするエリア、+で始まるメソッドを列挙するエリア、init(With...)で始まるコンストラクター、上位クラスをオーバーライドするメソッドの定義、@synthesyzeではフォローしきれない、副作用のあるプロパティのアクセッサー、IBActionで呼ばれるユーザーインターフェイスに反応するアクション、クラス外に公開するメソッド、クラス外に公開しないメソッド、TableViewやXMLPerserに呼ばれるデリゲートメソッドという風に分割しています。
基本的な考えはkratosさんと一緒ですね。あとは出来るだけ最大公約数的に分類して、自分がメソッドを見つけやすく出来れば良いと思います。
これを更にDashなどのスニペットツールに登録しておいて、クラスファイルを作成した時は無条件に貼り付けるようにしています。
Dashはスニペットツールとしても、クラス・メソッドリファレンスとしても優れているので導入をお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます。スニペットツールというものをはじめて知りました！Dash使ってみます！（僕は今までEvernoteにコードを貯めてコピペしてました。笑）

Comment: DashやTypinatorの様なキーワード型のスニペットツールは、キーワードの先頭一文字をダブらせると、既存のワードと重複して思わぬ所にスニペットが入らなくて便利と言う記事を見かけて、僕もそれに習っています。今回の例ですと、`///MARK:`と打つとその場所にスニペットが挿入されるようにすると便利だと思いますのでお試し下さい。

Answer (score 2):

良いかどうかはわかりませんが、私は普段以下のように分類しています

```
//MARK: - フィールド
...略

//MARK: - イニシャライザ
...略

//MARK: - メソッド
...略

//MARK: configure
...略

//MARK: handler
```

ざっとですが、このような感じです。

MARKのあとに`-`をつけるかつけないかで、プレビューも変わってきます。
これで大見出しと小見出しは分けることができると思います。

そしてあまり細かく分類はしません。
質問者様のようにたくさんのメソッドができる場合においては、
私はクラスを分けることで解決しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！勉強になります。細かく分けずにメソッド名で判別できるようにするのは大切かもしれませんね。クラスで分けるというのは、例えばUISliderに関するメソッドをひとつのクラスにまとめて書くというようなことでしょうか？

Comment: 私も初学者ですので、一般的なことは言えませんが、「単にメソッドをまとめたクラスを作る」のではなく、一つのオブジェクトとしてクラスを設計するのが良いと思います。その画像だけではわからないのですが、おそらくaddSliderというUISliderのインスタンスがあって、addSliderのイベントをメソッドがそれぞれ受け取っていると思います。私の場合UISliderを継承したAddSliderというクラスを作成し、イベント検知はDelegateによって渡すようにしています。ただ、この話はクラス設計の話になるため、メソッドの分類方法とは質問の主旨が変わってくると思いますので、より良いクラス設計については別途調べることをお勧めします。

Comment: 理解できました。UISliderのサブクラスをつくって、メソッドを定義して、addSlider.resetValue()のように呼び出して使うということですね。そのあたりはクラス設計の話になるのですね。ありがとうございます。